# Copying from Emacs to other tmux pane (code execution for Ipython, sql, bash, etc)?

Tags: bash, terminal, emacs, tmux, copy-paste

My preferred setup is running a terminal window with several tmux panes (a couple of shells, and an emacs session). What is the easiest way to send code from the emacs pane to be executed in the shell panes? For me this specifically means stuff like IPython, MySQL, bash, etc. Right now I have just been using copy paste with the mouse; this is suboptimal for obvious reasons.

**Note**: I do know that I can just run a shell in Emacs. However I don't like how all of the commands change/color changes from my normal shell (using different theme for emacs). If there is a way to set up the emacs shell perfectly like the normal shell I would also entertain that option.

Comment: There's [tmux's copy paste](https://awhan.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/copy-paste-in-tmux/) feature, but you might find it even more awkward than the mouse =) For sending one line of input to the same window you should be able to automate it though : make a key binding for it then you just need one keystroke.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "perfectly like the normal shell".  Which things don't work the way you like, and how would you like for them to work?  Just the colors?  Or interactive features like command-line editing, arrow keys, etc?

Comment: Colors, the same hotkeys, a way to lock into the command line and not accidentally edit the rest of the file, etc